# How do I view valid AMP pages in mobile Google search results?

Tags: amp-html

I've confirmed over 100 valid AMP pages in my site with Google webmaster tools. How do I actually view these pages inside google mobile search results? Googling these pages on my phone only returns the canonical version of these amp pages. Does Google only return a curated set of valid amp pages?

Comment: What is your website? Also, AFAIK, only the following listed [Schema.org types](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/articles) are currently displayed in Google search results right now.

Comment: Here's a valid amp page as an example. https://www.digitalsurgeons.com/thoughts/amp/the-blockchain-revolution/

Comment: I noticed some interesting things in your Schema.org mark up. The "mainEntityOfPage" should link to the canonical and the "dateModified" states 1974-... That date might be affecting it greatly since they mostly only show the latest articles in the carousel. Try that and let's see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. Good spot - I'll update those schema values and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @Andrew Well that didn't seem to do the trick :( I'm at a loss.

Comment: Maybe Google is discriminating Against the smaller guys and only has the carousel for breaking news since AMP is still pretty new. I spent weeks just trying to see which terms produces a carousel and it seems like it's mainly breaking news, what's trending, and names of cities/countries.

Comment: But I'll take another look at your pages when I get a chance to and see if I can find anything else that might be affecting them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMP team member here –

I'm pretty sure you are referring to the Top Stories carousel – in which case I have bad news for you. There's no way to guarantee you'll appear in the carousel if you build a valid AMP page. The carousel is a specific product focussed on the latest top news, and simply doesn't surface all sorts of AMP pages.

However, have a look at our [latest Dev Preview](https://webmasters.googleblog.com/2016/08/amp-your-content-preview-of-amped.html) where you can try out the next iteration of AMP in Google, showing AMP pages directly in the organic search results. If your pages validate, they should show up with the AMP badge after searching for them, like so:

[image: AMP in blue links]