# AMP page not appearing in some Mobile During search

Tags: html, seo, google-search, amp-html, canonical-link

I have made the AMP page for my website following the [Google docs](https://www.ampproject.org/). Then I performed its validation and everything is fine in there as well.
I have linked the AMP and non-AMP pages too as follow:

Non-AMP page:

```
<link rel="amphtml" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/amp/document.html">
```

AMP page:

```
<link rel="canonical" href="https://www.example.com/url/to/full/document.html">
```

And finally, I'm getting the AMP version in Google Search in my mobile. But in some of the mobile phones it's not working as expected. It's not showing the AMP version in the search result.

In my website:
The URL to the home page is: `https://www.example.com/`
The URL to the AMP page is: `https://www.example.com/amp/`

Is this problem due to the cache issue of the mobile or depends upon the mobile or due to the AMP indexing issue? Or is it due to the URL issue? Does it depend upon the URL like `https://www.example.com/?amp` and not `https://www.example.com/amp`?

PS: In most of the mobile it worked. In some it didn't. The site URL mentioned above is just the example.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a [blog](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/amp-page-not-showing-in-google-search/) that stated "However, at some point you should be able to see your posts with lightning bolt in SERPS on compatible device/browser." See [proper indexing](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls) so there's a bi-directional `rel="canonical"` and `rel="alternate"` between mobile and desktop versions of content. There are also related SO posts - [How do I view valid AMP pages in mobile Google search results?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38800018/5995040) and [Google AMP - displaying AMP-enabled pages only when accessed via Google search results](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39106326/5995040) both discussed limitation and things how to properly make an AMP page. They also stated that:

> It is up to you if you want to send visitors to AMP pages or not from your website. The way The Guardian, and most other publishers, has set it up is that there is both an AMP and non-AMP page. If you visit their site directly, you will be served the non-AMP page. So only the AMP pages are served when accessed from the Google search results carousel or accessed directly by the AMP URL.

Hope this helps.