# Why AMP pages are shown on mobile simulator, but not phone devices

Tags: amp-html

Now I searched keywords like "CNN news" on google Chrome's mobile mode in Mac, then it shows AMP pages with lightning bolts. But it doesn't be shown on my iphone or iPad. 
And the linked pages are, https://edition-m.cnn.com/2018/10/11/us/hurricane-michael-tropical-storm-wxc/index.html on iPad, and https://www.google.com/amp/s/amp.cnn.com/cnn/2018/10/11/us/hurricane-michael-tropical-storm-wxc/index.html on Chrome's mobile mode in Mac.

Is this bug?

[added]
This question is not for amp-stories nor amp-carousel. This is for normal search results linking to amp pages.

Comment: Read the following links: https://github.com/Automattic/amp-wp/issues/140 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38382430/how-do-i-view-valid-amp-pages-in-mobile-google-search-results/38800018#38800018 , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39096072/google-amp-displaying-amp-enabled-pages-only-when-accessed-via-google-search-r/39106326#39106326. It was discussed there how the amp page responds to mobile devices.

Comment: @MαπμQμαπkγVπ.0 Those info are less relevant. Even CNN news, the famous AMP publisher, are down for AMP pages, that I meant. Or Did you confirm that it works on your device and responded my question?  And please don't put links to old articles, those are published in 2016. Situations for AMP has been largely changed for 2 years.